# A problem about $2-SAT$

Tags: algorithms

My algorithm $n$ times checking that  $n$ clauses with $2$ variable, are satisfiable or not? (i.e. $n$ times my algorithm check $2-SAT$ Problem with different variable) that each time $2-SAT$ need's $O(n)$, so the running time will be $O(n^2)$. Are there a hint or idea such that  prohibit my algorithm from doing repeated work?

Comment: reduce the running time of *what*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ instances of $2-SAT$, each with size of $m$.

You have a total of $n\cdot m$ symbols, and you will *have* to at least read all of them (to solve a particular $2-SAT$ instance you need to read the entire $2-SAT$ formula).

Hence you need at least $\Omega(n\cdot m)$.